# swift unhide buttons in one column if mouse is over row

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I working with swift 4 for osx.
I have a view based NSTableView with 4 columns.
the cells in each column has got the same custom cell class:

```
class CustomCell: NSTableCellView {


    @IBOutlet weak var btnInfo: NSButton!

    private var trackingArea: NSTrackingArea!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(
            rect: bounds,
            options: [.activeAlways, .mouseEnteredAndExited],
            owner: self,
            userInfo: nil
        )
        addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
    }


    override func mouseEntered(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseEntered(with: event)
            btnInfo.isHidden = false
    }

    override func mouseExited(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseExited(with: event)
            btnInfo.isHidden = true
    }


}
```

Now i would like to realize the following situation:

if the user goes with the mouse over a row, the btnInfo should be visible and hide again, it the mouse leaves the row.

problem is (with the code above), that my apps crashes, because btnInfo will be nil

Logically: Because this button is only in column 4 available.
in all other columns it will be nil.

how can i solve this?

Comment: You can use multiple table cell views. Return this cell view for column 4 and return the default – or another custom cell view – for the others.

Comment: You are doing it at a wrong place.  That's not NSTableCellView's job as it's not a controller.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add an `NSTrackingArea` to the entire view, not the individual cells. Then on the entire table view, you can get the mouse move events, take the `NSEvent`'s `locationInWindow`. Then `NSTableView` has a method `row(at point: NSPoint) -> Int` that can get you the current row that should be highlighting the button.